# Combining Predicate in SwiftData

Tags: swift, nspredicate, predicate, swift-data

I'm trying to combine multiple Predicates of the Type with and / or.
Previously with CoreData and NSPredicate I'd just do this:

```swift
let predicate = NSPredicate(value: true)
let predicate2 = NSPredicate(value: false)
let combinedPred = NSCompoundPredicate(type: .or, subpredicates: [predicate, predicate2])
```

Is there a comparable way to do this using SwiftData and #Predicate?
And if not, how could I implement a way to create partial conditions beforehand and combine them in a predicate later?

The only way I've found of doing this as an expression is like this, but this would make my predicate hundredths of lines long

```
let includeOnlyFavorites = true
#Predicate { includeOnlyFavorites ? $0.isFavorite : true }
```

---

### Context:

I'm developing an App that allows users to save and query items using shortcut actions. The items are stored using SwiftData and queried using EntityPropertyQuery

Apple implements the Query properties like this:

```
static var properties = QueryProperties {
    Property(\BookEntity.$title) {
        EqualToComparator { NSPredicate(format: "title = %@", $0) }
        ContainsComparator { NSPredicate(format: "title CONTAINS %@", $0) }
    }
}
```

and later combines the predicates with `NSCompoundPredicate`.

---

### Tried and failed:

Closure with Bool return:

```
let isFavorite = { (item: Item) in item.isFavorite }
let predicate = #Predicate<Item> { isFavorite($0) }
```

- won't work because Predicate does not allow global functions
- i also tried creating an object IsFavoriteFilter with an `evaluate(Item) -> Bool` method but I also can't use that

I also thought i might be able to use StandardPredicateExpression in another predicate because in the documentation it reads:

"A component expression that makes up part of a predicate, **and that's supported by the standard predicate type.**"
but there are no further explanations on this type

Comment: How would i do that though?
I need to create the conditions prior to creating the Predicate (when defining the EntityPropertyQuery)

and it's not possible to use functions in predicates

I can't use this `let isFavorite = { (item: Item) in item.isFavorite }`

in a predicate like this:
`let predicate = #Predicate<Item> { isFavorite($0) }`

Comment: The only way I've found of doing this as expressions is to define a boolean `includeOnlyFavorites` and do this: `includeOnlyFavorites ? $0.isFavorite : true`

Comment: I asked for a way to combine multiple predicates comparable to the way it works with NSPredicate. How else you describe my problem?

Comment: No it isn't. Using a custom function would just be *a* way to achieve my goal.
The key point is combining expressions in predicates or entire predicates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Building on [the answer by @orgtre](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77802872/11450810)

TLDR: [This Gist](https://gist.github.com/NoahKamara/d8660881b2ef8d6be18b8e26ed349bb7) implements two methods `conjunction()` and `disjunction()` on `Array<Predicate<T>>`

the reason for the error and subsequent crash is that the `PredicateExpressions.Variable` is used to resolve the Predicate input.

This is how Predicate Variable reolving works internally:

The Predicate you create looks something like this (when expanded):

```swift
let predicate = Foundation.Predicate<Person>({
    PredicateExpressions.build_contains(
        PredicateExpressions.build_KeyPath(
            root: PredicateExpressions.build_Arg($0),
            keyPath: \.name
        ),
        PredicateExpressions.build_Arg("Luke")
    )
})
```

The closure takes parameters of  `PredicateExpressions.Variable<Input>` which you need to pass as an argument to your expression `$0`

This variable will be unique for every predicate you created, meaning when you combine them using just the `predicate.expression` property, each expression has a distinct Variable leading to a `unresolved Variable` error.

I created a custom `StandardPredicateExpression` that takes a predicate and a variable and will do the following in it's evaluate method:

```swift
struct VariableWrappingExpression<T>: StandardPredicateExpression {
    let predicate: Predicate<T>
    let variable: PredicateExpressions.Variable<T>
    
    func evaluate(_ bindings: PredicateBindings) throws -> Bool {
        // resolve the variable
        let value: T = try variable.evaluate(bindings)
        
        // bind the variable of the predicate to this value
        let innerBindings = bindings.binding(predicate.variable, to: value)

        // evaluate the expression with those bindings
        return try predicate.expression.evaluate(innerBindings)
    }
}
```

Extending the excellent work by [@orgtre](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77802872/11450810) to create a solution that takes an array of predicates and a closure for combining them

```swift
extension Predicate {    
    typealias Expression = any StandardPredicateExpression<Bool>
    
    static func combining<T>(
        _ predicates: [Predicate<T>],
        nextPartialResult: (Expression, Expression) -> Expression
    ) -> Predicate<T> {
        return Predicate<T>({ variable in
            let expressions = predicates.map({
                VariableWrappingExpression<T>(predicate: $0, variable: variable)
            })
            guard let first = expressions.first else {
                return PredicateExpressions.Value(true)
            }
            
            let closure: (any StandardPredicateExpression<Bool>, any StandardPredicateExpression<Bool>) -> any StandardPredicateExpression<Bool> = {
                nextPartialResult($0,$1)
            }
            
            return expressions.dropFirst().reduce(first, closure)
        })
    }
}

let compound = Predicate<Person>.combine([predicateA, predicateB]) {
    func buildConjunction(lhs: some StandardPredicateExpression<Bool>, rhs: some StandardPredicateExpression<Bool>) -> any StandardPredicateExpression<Bool> {
        PredicateExpressions.Conjunction(lhs: lhs, rhs: rhs)
    }
    
    return Predicate<T>.combining(self, nextPartialResult: {
        buildConjunction(lhs: $0, rhs: $1)
    })
}
```

Check [this Gist](https://gist.github.com/NoahKamara/d8660881b2ef8d6be18b8e26ed349bb7) for an implementation

Answer (score 13):

Wow. This was hard, but i've found a solution to my problem:

If we use `PredicateExpression` instead of Predicate we can later build a predicate like this:

```swift
let expression = PredicateExpressions.Value(true)

let predicate = Predicate<String>({ input in
    expression
})
```

The next step was injecting the input.
I chose to just create a closure that takes a variable and returns an expression (because the initialiser that takes expressions does not provide a value, but a variable)

```swift
let variableExp = { (variable: PredicateExpressions.Variable<String>) in
    let value = PredicateExpressions.Value("Hello There")
    
    return PredicateExpressions.Equal(
        lhs: variable,
        rhs: value
    )
}

let variablePredicate = Predicate<String>({ input in
    variableExp(input)
})
```

### Example with Model

Swift Data Model:

```
@Model
class Book {
    @Attribute
    var title: String
    
    @Attribute
    var lastReadDate: Date
    
    init(title: String, lastReadDate: Date) {
        self.title = title
        self.lastReadDate = lastReadDate
    }
}
```

Create Closures for the expressions we want to use.

```
typealias BookVariable = PredicateExpressions.Variable<Book>
typealias BookKeyPath<T> = PredicateExpressions.KeyPath<BookVariable,T>

let dateEquals = { (input: BookKeyPath<Date>, _ value: Date) in
    return PredicateExpressions.Equal(
        lhs: input,
        rhs: PredicateExpressions.Value(value)
    )
}
```

The actual filtering:

```
// Do we want to filter by date at all?
let filterByDate = true

// The date we want to test against
let testDate = Date.now

let variablePredicate = Predicate<Book>({ input in
    // Wrap values
    let shouldFilterByDate = PredicateExpressions.Value(filterByDate)
    let alwaysTrue = PredicateExpressions.Value(true)
    
    // Create date Expression with testDate
    let dateExp = dateEquals(BookKeyPath(root: input, keyPath: \Book.lastReadDate), testDate)

    // Predicate that ,
    // if shouldFilterByDate evaluates to true returns dateExp result
    // otherwise returns expression that evaluates to true
    return PredicateExpressions.build_Conditional(
        shouldFilterByDate,
        dateExp,
        alwaysTrue
    )
})

let descriptor = FetchDescriptor(predicate: variablePredicate)
modelContext.fetch(descriptor)
```

Comment: How do you use this in a real example with a Model object?

Comment: Just replace it with a model context ... 

... these kinds of comments really aren't helpful are they?


(I've added a more extensive example with a Model object.)

Comment: Well helpful to me, upvoted.

Comment: I'm confused, the model example shown is just the same as
```
#Predicate<Book> { model in
  if filterByDate {
    model.lastReadDate == testDate
  }
  else {
    true
  }
}
```
Why do you need to construct the predicate expressions by hand? 

Comment: i can build the expressions by hand to create filters on the fly. 
things like EntityPropertyQuery from AppKit expects you to work with an array of filters specifying keypath & comparators.
If i were to do it with the predicate macro, i would neet to write a huge macro covering all cases for all keypaths, this way i can abstract all string properties to a StringFilter type

Answer (score 5):

Generalizing [the answer by nOk](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76861465/13466303) a bit using [a suggestion on the Swift Forums](https://forums.swift.org/t/pitch-swift-predicates/62000/50) I've had success with this procedure for combining SwiftData predicates:

First write out each predicate using the [#Predicate](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/predicate) macro and make sure they work individually (failures at runtime happen frequently even without compilation errors). Here is an example of a `Predicate`:

```
let predicate1 = #Predicate<Item> { item in
    ...
}
```

Next, right-click on each use of `#Predicate` and select "Expand Macro". This might take quite some time and if the expansion doesn't appear (this happened often for me), I've found that it might help to simplify the predicate by splitting it up, removing a few "||" or "&&" conditions, rewriting it in other ways, or transferring it to an essentially equivalent simpler dummy project.

An expanded `#Predicate` macro looks something like this:

```
let predicate1 = Foundation.Predicate<Item>({ item in
    PredicateExpressions.xxx(
      ...
    )
})
```

Copy everything in the expansion **except the first and last line** and assign it to a constant:

```
let expression1 = PredicateExpressions.xxx( ... )
```

Repeat for each predicate. After seeing a few of these expansions you might also try to directly modify or write the [PredicateExpression](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/predicateexpression) manually (this is essential for more complex cases the `#Predicate` macro can't handle).

Once you have a bunch of predicate expressions stored in constants, say named expression1 to expression3, you can conditionally combine them into one `Predicate`, for example by forming their conjunction like this:

```
func makePredicate(useExpression1: Bool, useExpression2: Bool, useExpression3: Bool) -> Predicate<Item> {

    func buildConjunction(lhs: some StandardPredicateExpression<Bool>, rhs: some StandardPredicateExpression<Bool>) -> any StandardPredicateExpression<Bool> {
        PredicateExpressions.Conjunction(lhs: lhs, rhs: rhs)
    }

    return Predicate<Item>({ item in
        var conditions: [any StandardPredicateExpression<Bool>] = []

        let expression1 = PredicateExpressions.xxx( ... )

        let expression2 = PredicateExpressions.xxx( ... )

        let expression3 = PredicateExpressions.xxx( ... )

        if useExpression1 {
            conditions.append(expression1)
        }
        if useExpression2 {
            conditions.append(expression2)
        }
        if useExpression3 {
            conditions.append(expression3)
        }

        guard let first = conditions.first else {
            return PredicateExpressions.Value(true)
        }

        let closure: (any StandardPredicateExpression<Bool>, any StandardPredicateExpression<Bool>) -> any StandardPredicateExpression<Bool> = {
            buildConjunction(lhs: $0, rhs: $1)
        }

        return conditions.dropFirst().reduce(first, closure)
    })
}

let combinedPredicate = makePredicate(useExpression1: true, useExpression2: true, useExpression3: true)
```

A few notes:

- This assumes that each predicate only has one argument of type `Item` named `item`.
- Replace `PredicateExpressions.Conjunction` with `PredicateExpressions.Disjunction` in the function `buildConjunction` (and preferably rename it) to combine the predicates using logical OR instead.
- I have found no way to directly use each predicates related expression, if I instead use `let expression1 = predicate1.expression` it just crashes at runtime.
- By circumventing the `#Predicate` macro like this and directly using `PredicateExpressions` one can construct much more advanced predicates than the `#Predicate` macro can handle. If one still runs into a "unable to type-check this expression in reasonable time"-error one could just split out any `PredicateExpression` into a further constant.

Comment: I was able to use an array of Predicates with array.map { $0.expression }

Comment: nevermind, it crashed on me too, but i found the reason and an (as i think) elegant solution